# Traffic accounting with iptables with multiple chains

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a linux firewall setup with 3 zones: 
- green for LAN (192.168.0.0/24)
- blue for WLAN (192.168.1.0/24)
- orange for DMZ (192.168.2.0/24)

All zones have systems running and I want to know what traffic to external each system is producing. Doing some test there was/must always be some internal traffic because vnstat on the external device showed different traffic accounts.

Doing some reseach I ended up with something like this (example for one internal IP and only for upload):

```
/sbin/iptables -N TRAFFICFILTERUP
/sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -j TRAFFICFILTERUP
/sbin/iptables -A TRAFFICFILTERUP -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
/sbin/iptables -A TRAFFICFILTERUP -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j RETURN
/sbin/iptables -A TRAFFICFILTERUP -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j RETURN
/sbin/iptables -A TRAFFICFILTERUP -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j RETURN
/sbin/iptables -A TRAFFICFILTERUP -j LOG
/sbin/iptables -N TRAFFICUP
/sbin/iptables -A TRAFFICFILTERUP -j TRAFFICUP
/sbin/iptables -A TRAFFICUP -s 192.168.2.1
```

Results:

```
iptables -L TRAFFICUP -nvx
Chain TRAFFICUP (1 references)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out    source     destination
0        0            all  --  *      *       192.168.2.1   0.0.0.0/0

iptables -L TRAFFICFILTERUP -nvx
Chain TRAFFICFILTERUP (1 references)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source destination         
0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8         
0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.0/24      
0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.0/24      
1349   271065 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.0/24      
402   171503 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4
401   171249 TRAFFICUP  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Why is there no traffic in TRAFFICUP? Any suggestions or is the whole approach wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
/sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -j TRAFFICFILTERUP
```

should be

```
/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -j TRAFFICFILTERUP
```